# Cannot Resolve Symbol activity_sign_up

Tags: java, android, android-activity, material-components-android

It says that "cannot resolve the symbol activity_sign_up" when I created a new empty activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
}
```

Added xml resource file code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SignUp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the project and check. If it didn't work just restart the Android studio. Happens for most of the people. Let me know if it worked or will try to help you out differently.